# How can I produce this graph with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is the basic graph R presents when plotting a data frame.

```
plot(df)
```

It displays the relationship between all variables.

[image: the plot]

I know about faceting in `ggplot2` but it's used for partition according to specific variables. I want to facet by a target parameter (for color) and split the grid by the variables.

sample data:

```
prediction.date  mean.forcast   mean.Error    standard.Deviation    AIC         param.u param.v
2012-08-29       0.0015608102   0.008296402   0.008296402           -6.165365   2       5
2012-08-30      -0.0002720289   0.008537309   0.008537309           -6.164167   2       4
2012-09-02      -0.0014277972   0.008194409   0.008194409           -6.168868   4       0
2012-09-03       0.0016537998   0.008062687   0.008062687           -6.176634   5       3
2012-09-04      -0.0030247699   0.007885009   0.007885009           -6.181844   4       3
2012-09-05       0.0001538991   0.007524703   0.007524703           -6.197240   3       4
```

Comment: Colour scales and faceting can be done at the same time in ggplot2 if your data is in the right shape. Really, it's just a matter of the right `melt()` incantation. Some dummy data would be helpful here.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you mean by: " facet by a target parameter (for color) and split the grid by the variables. "

Comment: i want to visualize the relationship between all the variables - just like the graph i attached. but, since this is a regression result i have another boolean variable - lets call it - `is.model.correct`. i want each dot in the graph to be green if `is.model.correct==1` and red otherwise. Thanks.

Comment: The `GGally` package  and `ggpairs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to color points in plot you provided, then you can use argument `col=` in `plot()` and set names of colors and variable to use in determining color.

```
#variable of test result (should be the same length as number of rows in df)
test.result<-c(0,1,1,0,0,1)

plot(df[,3:7],col=c("green","red")[as.factor(test.result)])
```

[image]